# Regex for number seperated with / and comma?

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone help with regex generation for slash and comma seperated numbers? Exampla matching patterns are as below

Valid

```
123/123
123/123, 111/156
```

Invalid

```
123,123
123/123,123
123,123/123
123/123,1111/156,
```

Comment: Glad to see your test cases! I often start with a tool like regex101.com, it has a quick reference to help build a working pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^\d+\/\d+(, \d+\/\d+)*$` should work.

`^...$` means that it has to be the whole string, `\d+` means "match 1 or more digits ( match a number )". `\d+\/\d+` matches 2 numbers separated by a slash. `(, \d+\/\d+)*` matches any additional number pairs only if they are separated by a comma.

Comment: 123/123,123/156 this case is failing with above regex

Comment: Thats becasue there is no space, you didn't specify behaviour for no spaces so I assumed you wanted them. Replace the space in the regex with `( )*` and it willl work.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
^((\d+\/\d+)(,\s|$))+
```

Comment: 123/123,123/156 this use case is failing